# iPhone Why does only newly inserted data show up in my UITableView associated with a fetchedResultController?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data

For a learning project, I'm building an app that allows a user to capture images and tag them.  I'm using CoreData to store images and tags names.  In the app, I initially show a UITable that lists all tags with the number of images with that tag as a row subtitle.  There's a separate part of the app where users can take a picture and tag it with one or more tags.  Taking the pictures and tagging seems to work fine.  I can look in the database and see everything is appropriate.

The problem is when I initially enter the app.  Even though there are images in the database, it shows nothing in the UITableView.  After opening the app, if I then take a picture and tag it, it then shows up in the UITableView - and the image count reflects all images in the database with that tag.  Other tags not referenced by the newly added image do NOT show up.  If I take another picture and add a tag associated with other images, the new tag shows up in the UITableView and the image count reflects all images with that tag.  It is as thought the app is only recognizing data it has seen (cache??) and not the whole database.

I'm not sure what code is most relevant, but I suspect the problem must be associated with how I'm attaching the fetchedResultsController to the UITableView.  Here is the code for that function which is called in the viewDidLoad function:

```
-(void) setupFetchedResultsController
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Tag"];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];

    MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [appDelegate.imagesDatabase managedObjectContext];
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName: nil];
}
```

I've confirmed that this is called before the view renders.  Can someone shed light on what's going on?

Comment: Figured out what the issue was.  I have to make sure that the above function is called WITHIN the success handler called upon completion of opening the database (e.g., UIManagedDocument openWithCompletionHandler).  Simply calling this later in the code or even using a BOOL switched within the success handler wasn't sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are not fetching any records.

You should use the `UIFetchedResultsController` pattern provided by the apple code templates. Basically, you "lazily" instantiate the fetched results controller. You can then conveniently set it to `nil` and it will recreate itself, including performing a new fetch with the updated data.

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController*) fetchedResultsController {
    if (fetchedResultsController_ != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController_;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tag" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![aFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error in fetchedResultsController : %@", error); 
    }
    return aFetchedResultsController;
}
```

As you can see, this code implies that you should have these properties in your view controller: `managedObjectContext` and `fetchedResultsController`. Get a reference to the app delegate's managed object context when you instantiate the controller.

Start a new project in Xcode and choose "Master-Detail" and then tick "Use Core Data" to get a full template.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was able to determine the problem which was that I my code that set the fetchedResponseController was being executed before the database was successfully opened.  The only was to guarantee that it runs after was to call the code only as a result of the completionHandler being called with a success of "yes".

Comment: I hope this helped. If it did, please check the tick mark above.

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering if you need to be using NSFetchedResultsController.

Is there any reason why you could not do something like:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Tag"];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];

MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [appDelegate.imagesDatabase managedObjectContext];
NSArray *fetchResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request];
```

And then just use that array in you tableViewController to populate your table..?

Hope this is of some use to you, if I can be of any more help, let me know :)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The reason for the NSFetchResultsController is to "automate" the synching of the database with the UITableView.  For instance, if I have a background operation (via the same ManagedObjectContext) the table will automagically update with the new data.  Your response did inspire me to test without the NSFetchedResults controller, which lead me to the underlying issue (see above).  Thanks again.